# SharePoint Online JSON Column Formatting, if colum text is empty

Tags: json, forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm a big beginner with Json. Literally less than an hours experience.

I have a microsoft form that poulates a list within a SharePoint site, via a flow. I want to format a few of the colums so that if they have been left empty within the form, the text displayed will be 'N/A'.

Before anyone suggests it, I have tried setting the colums default value, but as the flow populates each row with whatever is in the microsoft form, it overwrites the default value with empty string.

Could there be another way to do this? An if statement within the flow maybe? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below code in JSON formatting:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=if(@currentField=='','N/A',@currentField)"
}
```

Test result:

[image]